# QField unable to load compressed TIFF files

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, qfield, compression

I have come across the following error in QField when trying to load transformed and compressed GeoTIFFs. All uncompressed TIFFs seem to load fine.

> The following layers could not be loaded, please review and reconfigure the QGIS project

All the paths in my project are relative (as recommended) so I am not sure why I am receiving this error. The raster data is compressed via the GUI (tested with asc, xyz and TIFF to TIFF):

*Right Click -> Export -> Save As -> GeoTiff with a high compression*

I understand the official recommendation (https://qfield.org/docs/project-management/dataformat.html#raster-data) is to use a geopackage raster with pyramids, however my goal is to create a workflow for people with limited GIS understanding/patience (forestry). So far compressed TIFFs are easy to create and function well in QGIS.

Comment: If you double click on Deflate you can change it to lzw.  I've had no problems with those, but maybe deflate would have worked too.   But it is easy enough for you to test.  I also converted floating point to integer/8 bit  unsigned since the project packages included canopy height maps from 1m LiDAR which were quite large to start.

Comment: @johns LZW worked a charm! I also noticed my predictor was throwing an error however testing with the correct predictor Deflate still didn't show up, whereas LZW worked fine. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: I don't find "GeoTiff with a hight compression" in QGIS. What are the exact potions you used?
In general, JP2k (JPEG2000) gives quite good compression rates.

Answer (score 1):

If you double click on Deflate you can change it to lzw. I've had no problems with those, but maybe deflate would have worked too. But it is easy enough for you to test. I also converted floating point to integer/8 bit unsigned since the project packages included canopy height maps from 1m LiDAR which were quite large to start.